# Social Media Buttons Does not appear on BlogSpot

Tags: javascript, html, css, templates, blogger

I am Newbie !just found a Blog Template and when i installed it ,just 2 social media buttons appear(search and rss) and other 2 (facebook and twitter)does not appear

Here's a IMAGE EXAMPLE
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-iW_hyjFwQ-Y/VbqBMhvnU_I/AAAAAAAAAnk/BMcD_1sOPk4/s572-Ic42/23.jpg

here the full template so can some one correct it
   Here's a [FULL TEMPLAETS](http://pasted.co/92b1ad37/)

Comment: please include your code so we can help

Answer (score 0):

I have installed the template you provided and I can see the twitter and facebook icons.

I have also tried the absolute url's provided by the template.

http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-DGAsYU4zLTc/UYxtwmuGooI/AAAAAAAAJRU/IP26z8wURDI/s000/facebook.png

http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-xyeOtoNgPoE/UYxtuVn4k2I/AAAAAAAAJRM/t1VqDJ_6P-s/s000/twitter_bird.png

Everything seems fine. Try to empty your browser cache and reload the page again.

Hope it helps.

Comment: ,thank you for replied,,,yes it works , it was the adblocks plus , when i disabled it it appear , but why Rss and search appear even adblock enabled ,wondering ???

Comment: I can't tell you exactly why this happened. Maybe you have blocked some contents that where related to those icons somehow.